# diff of identical tar archive return they are not identical

Tags: bash, diff, tar

I have a script that generates a `tar` archive using the command

```
tar -zacf /tmp/foo.tar.gz /home/yotam/foo
```

it then check if a `tar` file is in a certain folder, and check if there is any changes between the two archives, if so, it keeps the new one

```
if ! [ -e /home/yotam/barr/foo.tar.gz ]; then
    cp /tmp/foo.tar.gz /home/yotam/bar/foo.tar.gz
    cond=1
else 
    #compare
    diff --brief <(sort /tmp/foo.tar.gz) <(sort /home/yotam/bar/foo.tar.gz) >/dev/null
    cond=$?

fi

if [ $cond -eq 1 ]; then
    rm /home/yotam/bar/foo.tar.gz
    cp /tmp/foo.tar.gz /home/yotam/foo.tar.gz
fi
```

However, this script always view the two archive files as different, even if I'm not doing anything in any of the two archives or the `foo` folder itself. What is wrong with my check?

Edit:

for what it worth, replacing the `diff` file with

```
diff --brief  /tmp/foo.tar.gz /home/yotam/bar/foo.tar.gz >/dev/null
```

yield the same result.

Comment: it looks a bit weird to me the `sort file.gz`. Shouldn't you `cat file.gz |sort`? I don't think `sort` can handle gzipped files.

Comment: @fedorqui the two options you mention are the same. Anyway, sorting a gz or tar file does not make much sense...

Comment: @Diego op true, I wanted to say `zcat file.gz | sort`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that gzip archive can be used as a hash-function. Perhaps gzip packaging implementation relies on current date-time and then produces different output for each execution.

I'd recommend to use some widely used hash function. Take a look at git internal hash implementation - `shasum`, for example.

More at: [How does git compute file hashes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7225313/how-does-git-compute-file-hashes)

Comment: yes there must be some time field in the way. If, instead, you diff the tar archive they are identical, weird hehe

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're doing a line-wise compare of zipped tar archives, after sorting the lines. There are multiple reasons why this is a bad idea (for one: sorting by like for something that is gzipped doesn't make sense). To check whether 2 files, either use `diff file1 file2`, or calculate a hash for each file (with `md5`/`md5sum filename`) and compare those.

The problem is that gzip adds the name of the files it gzips in the zip archive. If you have 2 identical files and then gzip these, you will get 2 different archives.

So what can you do to solve this? For one you can compare gunziped versions of both files: `diff <(gzcat out/out2.tar.gz) <(gzcat out2.tar.gz)`. I assume you have the `sort` in there in case the files get tarred in a different order, but I don't think you have to worry about that. If that is a problem for you, check out something like [tarsum](http://www.guyrutenberg.com/2009/04/29/tarsum-02-a-read-only-version-of-tarsum/). This will give you a better result, since if you use sort, you will not notice moving a line from one file to the other, or switching two lines in a file.