# Why does Git store (and hash) blob size in the blob file?

Tags: git, hash, architecture, blob

Git's blob object file format is `blob <size string>\0<data>`.
The blob-identifying SHA-1 hash is calculated not from the blob contents alone, but from the header-augmented blob data (as described above).

As a purist I do not like that architecture. It mixes the universal property of the data (its SHA1 hash) with some git-specific header.

Another advantage of pure-data blob storage is that the files can be added to the index using "copy-on-write" instead of copying the whole file. The required space could be halved and some operations could become faster.

So, why did Git developers choose to use the header-based format instead of the pure data format?

P.S. AFAIK in the early days of Git the SHA-1 hash was based on the compressed data.

Comment: I can only really guess as to "why" but I suspect it's so that git can read the first block of the object, decompress, and see how much memory to malloc() for the full decompressed object.

Answer (score 5):

> AFAIK in the early days of Git the SHA-1 hash was based on the compressed data.

Yes, and that lead to all kind of "optimizations" like [commit 65c2e0c, git 0.99, June 2015](https://github.com/git/git/commit/65c2e0c349aa5c7f605defb52dc67f1b3658a1b9):

> Find size of SHA1 object without inflating everything.

But that new format, illustrated in "[How does git compute file hashes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7225313/6309)", can be traced back to:

- `git diff`, in [commit 051308f (git 1.4.0-rc1, May 2006)](https://github.com/git/git/commit/051308f6e9cebeb76b8fb4f52b7e9e7ce064445c)
- `git fast-import`, started in [commit db5e523 (git 1.5.0, Aug. 2006)](https://github.com/git/git/commit/db5e523fddd2a1a47d9ea63498734d0141925513)

Each time, the length of the data is needed to do anything with the data itself.