# Compute Github API file SHA

Tags: github, github-api, github-api-v3

I have a file whose contents are "from test" - 9 bytes. The documentation says that the SHA of created files is computed using SHA1:

> The file's SHA-1 hash is computed and stored in the blob object.

(from https://developer.github.com/v3/git/blobs/)

However, when I compute the hex-encoded SHA1 output of "from test", I get `5669556d9a5c27fdd649dcaaa0873757c2aa402f`.

The Github API says that the SHA is `62b551731eada762035d4665978027cd44291290` - this is the ETag returned and the value for "sha" in the API response for retrieving a file. In addition, when I call the CreateFile endpoint with "from test" as the value and `566955...` as the sha, I'm told that the SHA is incorrect.

I've also tried appending newlines, computing the SHA of the base64 encoded value of the content, computing the SHA of base64+ a trailing newline, and none of them give me `62b551731eada762035d4665978027cd44291290`. How is Github computing that value?

I've double checked the contents of the remote file are the same - "from test" - somehow the SHA is still different.

Comment: I thought [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7225313/354577) would be the answer, but that doesn't seem to match either.

Comment: That is the answer, you need to change 14 to 9.

Comment: Oh, good. I did change the byte count but didn't think it gave the right value. Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah - GitHub is computing the sum of `blob <length>\x00<contents>`, where length is the length in bytes of the content string and `\x00` is a single null byte.

`sha1("blob 9\x00from test")` yields the correct sum!

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/7225329/329700 for more info.

Comment: FWIW, this isn't a GitHub thing but rather a Git thing.