# Python compares two audio files

Tags: python, file, compare, mp3

How can I compare two audio files and check the match?
I tried importing the file and dividing it into parts and checking if each part was in the other file, but the code didn't work.
It makes sense to have small problems in one of the files and still the software will be able to recognize that the (songs) are the same

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check each file is identical you can *hash* each file and compare hashes.

A hash is a unique string that corresponds to a specific bit of data.

Here is how you can do it in Python:
[Hashing a file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22058048/hashing-a-file-in-python)

If you're on a Linux system you could use:

```
md5sum file1
```

On Windows Powershell:

```
Get-FileHash file1 -Algorithm MD5
```

Comment: How can this help me?

Comment: Well you're checking if two files match (the same)? Or am I mistaken?

Comment: Yes, but there can be small errors in one of the files and I want the code to still recognize that they are asking them (songs) audio files

Comment: Ok, no worries - my answer isn't relevant. Please update your question with that information

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following to compare audio files -

A. Check this lib
https://pypi.org/project/audiodiff/

B. Use scipy/librosa kind of libs to do following -

1. Comparing Fourier components (FFT-fast Fourier transformation) of two files
2. Getting audio fingerprints of two audios and comparing

Comment: I can't download the library