# Cannot hash every line on of a whole file on Python using VSC

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm using Python on VSC on a project, it requires me to hash the whole file (46KB with 5579 lines). However, on VSC, it only shows the hash table of the last 1012 lines. I didn't know what was happening and I could not fix it. This is my code:

```
import hashlib
def SHA1_hash(string):
    hash_obj = hashlib.sha1(string.encode())
    return(hash_obj.hexdigest())

with open("Project file/dict.txt") as f: 
    for line in f.readlines():
        print(SHA1_hash(line))
```

Picture of my text file starting from "writings":

[image]

The output should starts with:

```
5AD930D43A7851DC6649558BA6BEDD44F14E737C
(hash SHA-1 of "writings")
```

However, it is like this:

Picture of output terminal, the output started with a different hash string:

[image]

Why is this happening? Why am I getting the wrong hash as output?

Comment: Did you try to read the file as binary data so you don't have to encode the string?

Comment: You might be running into the VSC terminal's line length limit. Try outputting to a file.

Comment: why don't you edit your question of 2h ago, don't post images of text screen shots, do you expect me to type them to try to reproduce. Code/Text should be put in code blocks

Comment: prev question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71877502/9938317

Comment: Please attach the text file. Sometimes a few weird characters are thrown in and end up altering the hash. Try running `.strip()` on the string before encoding it.

Comment: You're not hashing the file correctly. Instead of just reposting your question, see [the duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22058048/hashing-a-file-in-python) which I linked in your previous question.

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, or Tracebacks. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`) ...
[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)...[Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) ... 
[You should not post code as an image because:...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2823755)

Comment: @aneroid That hashes the whole file at once, instead of each line.

Comment: the tool to use is a debugger, you can step line by line and inspect the content of the variables, **A VERY HANDY TOOL**, a lot faster than letting other people do the work

Comment: `string` is a buildin module, not very handy to name your variable that

Comment: for an old school `print` debugging, add the line `print(repr(line))` to the `for` loop, and to limit the output during debugging `for line in f.readlines()[:5]:`

Comment: another tip: Don't use spaces in a filename. One day it will bite you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the `\n` after every line(except last line), I can not get `5AD930D43A7851DC6649558BA6BEDD44F14E737C` of `writings`.

Take `print(SHA1_hash(line.strip()))` to replace `print(SHA1_hash(line))` can solve the problem.

But I must admit I can not reproduce your outputs, could you check the string in the `dict.txt` file?

Comment: `SHA1_hash('writings')` gives you `5ad93.......`

Comment: @rioV8 Yes it is, I think he has some indent or space in the txt file.

Comment: I once had the problem in a text file to find some text, turned out there where `zero-width spaces` in the file, you don't see them in the regular editor but with the hex editor it was clear, and `print(repr(line))` was also helpful

Comment: @rioV8 perfect.

Comment: Thank you so much. I think this is the answer, about the dict.txt, I did not copy the whole file with more than 5000 lines, which made a misunderstanding, so sorry for that.

Comment: @NghiaNguyen A F* simple `print(i)` in your program would have shown you: you only process 100 lines and not 5000

Comment: @rioV8 What is `i`? And how did they get output for 1012 lines when they only process 100?

Comment: @KellyBundy `i` is the result of a use of `enumerate` and 100 is just an example number < 5000, then `i` would show `0..1011` and not `0...4999`. An indication you could try to solve yourself instead of letting others spend time trying to solve your ..........

Comment: @rioV8 Solve my what?