# Why has my checksum calculator stopped printing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, md5, sha1, checksum

I was trying to write a small program to get the checksums of some files. Using the code mentioned [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7829658/1530429), I made this:

```
import hashlib
import sys
from functools import partial

def md5sum(filename):
    with open(filename, mode='rb') as f:
        d = hashlib.md5()
        for buf in iter(partial(f.read, 128), b''):
            d.update(buf)
    return d.hexdigest()

print(md5sum(sys.argv[0]))
```

That code works fine. However, when I try adding SHA1 support like so:

```
import hashlib
import sys
from functools import partial

def md5sum(filename):
    with open(filename, mode='rb') as f:
        d = hashlib.md5()
        for buf in iter(partial(f.read, 128), b''):
            d.update(buf)
    return d.hexdigest()

def sha1sum(filename):
    with open(filename, mode='rb') as f:
        d = hashlib.sha1()
        for buf in iter(partial(f.read, 128), b''):
            d.update(buf)
    return d.hexdigest()

if sys.argv[0] == 'md5':
    print(md5sum(sys.argv[1]))
elif sys.argv[0] == 'sha1':
    print(sha1sum(sys.argv[1]))
```

it stops printing the output (for both MD5 and SHA1). What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Try putting `print(sys.argv[0])` just before the `if` test at the end; you may not be getting the system argument you think you are (or maybe you should be using `sys.argv[1]` instead).

Comment: I've always preferred to use `optparse` for command line arguments, just my opinion. That way you don't have to bother with all the indexing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sys.argv[0]` is the name of the script; command line arguments are stored in `sys.argv[1:]`. You probably wanted to test `sys.argv[1]` instead:

```
if sys.argv[1] == 'md5':
    print(md5sum(sys.argv[2]))
elif sys.argv[1] == 'sha1':
    print(sha1sum(sys.argv[2]))
```

Note that your original 'working' version only ever calculated the MD5 hash of the script itself.

Comment: Good lord, I'm an idiot. I was wondering why the MD5 didn't match up. Thanks for the help!