# What is the internal format of a Git tree object?

Tags: git, git-ls-tree

What is the format of a Git tree object's content?

The content of a blob object is `blob [size of string] NUL [string]`, but what is it for a tree object?

Comment: I wrote a script and extracted the format of tree object from bytes. You can see my answer for more details.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3178566/deflate-command-line-tool on a simple tree object

Comment: For commit objects: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37438460/895245

Answer (score 53):

The format of a tree object:

```
tree [content size]\0[Entries having references to other trees and blobs]
```

The format of each entry having references to other trees and blobs:

```
[mode] [file/folder name]\0[SHA-1 of referencing blob or tree]
```

I wrote a script deflating tree objects. It outputs as follows:

```
tree 192\0
40000 octopus-admin\0 a84943494657751ce187be401d6bf59ef7a2583c
40000 octopus-deployment\0 14f589a30cf4bd0ce2d7103aa7186abe0167427f
40000 octopus-product\0 ec559319a263bc7b476e5f01dd2578f255d734fd
100644 pom.xml\0 97e5b6b292d248869780d7b0c65834bfb645e32a
40000 src\0 6e63db37acba41266493ba8fb68c76f83f1bc9dd
```

The number 1 as the first character of a mode shows that is reference to a blob/file. The example above, pom.xml is a blob and the others are trees.

Note that I added new lines and spaces after `\0` for the sake of pretty printing. Normally all the content has no new lines. Also I converted 20 bytes (i.e. the SHA-1 of referencing blobs and trees) into hex string to visualize better.

Comment: Could you post or describe your script to deflate these? (It seems to be different to other git objects, and not just a zlib deflate)

Comment: Ah ha, you mention just that (it's the hexification or the 20 bytes, great!)

Comment: @AndyHayden It is a ZLib inflate if you want to decompress it, not a ZLib deflate (compress). I've managed to decompress entire repositories of Git objects but I'm not too sure whether the initial commit should reference a `parent` field.

Comment: If you're interested in creating the git tree object manually from its contents, it's important to note that the [Entries having references to other trees and blobs] needs to be sorted alphabetically by [file/folder name] (aka path).

Comment: @emiorhan : how to compute content size ? Or more precisely it’s the size of what ?

Comment: if you plan to pass this object to `git hash-object -t tree --stdin` be sure to omit the `tree 192\0` header, as otherwise you'll get `fatal: corrupt tree file`

Comment: @RossFeller could you point to some reference and explain what will go wrong otherwise? I was able to create two different tree objects which differ by the order of entries without any problems.

Comment: @user2284570 re: content size - it's the size of the entire tree object itself.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a `\r\n` or generally some form of newline after `\0` in the tree specification you quoted? After all, in all examples, the stuff that comes after `\0` comes on the succeeding line.

Comment: @qbolec, if you change order of entries, then 2 identical trees will have different hash and appear as different trees.

Answer (score 45):

I try to elaborate a bit more on @lemiorhan answer, by means of a test repo.

#### Create a test repo

Create a test project in an empty folder:

```
$ echo ciao > file1            
$ mkdir folder1                 
$ echo hello > folder1/file2     
$ echo hola > folder1/file3
```

That is:

```
$ find -type f          
./file1                   
./folder1/file2           
./folder1/file3
```

Create the local Git repo:

```
$ git init 
$ git add . 
$ git write-tree 
0b6e66b04bc1448ca594f143a91ec458667f420e
```

The last command returns the hash of the top level tree.

#### Read a tree content

To print the content of a tree in human readable format use:

```
$ git ls-tree 0b6e66
100644 blob 887ae9333d92a1d72400c210546e28baa1050e44    file1  
040000 tree ab39965d17996be2116fe508faaf9269e903c85b    folder1
```

In this case `0b6e66` are the first six characters of the top tree. You can do the same for `folder1`.

To get the same content but in raw format use:

```
$ git cat-file tree 0b6e66
100644 file1 ▒z▒3=▒▒▒$ ▒►Tn(▒▒♣D40000 folder1 ▒9▒]▒k▒◄o▒▒▒i▒♥▒[%
```

The content is similar to the one physically stored as a file in compressed format, but it misses the initial string:

```
tree [content size]\0
```

To get the actual content, we need to uncompress the file storing the `c1f4bf` tree object. The file we want is -- given of the 2/38 path format --:

```
.git/objects/0b/6e66b04bc1448ca594f143a91ec458667f420e
```

This file is compressed with zlib, therefore we obtain its content with:

```
$ openssl zlib -d -in .git/objects/0b/6e66b04bc1448ca594f143a91ec458667f420e
tree 67 100644 file1 ▒z▒3=▒▒▒$ ▒►Tn(▒▒♣D40000 folder1 ▒9▒]▒k▒◄o▒▒▒i▒♥▒[%
```

We learn the tree content size is 67.

Note that, since the terminal is not made for printing binaries, it might eat some part of the string or show other weird behaviour. In this case pipe the commands above with `| od -c` or use the manual solution in the next section.

#### Generate manually the tree object content

To understand the tree generation process we can generate it ourselves starting from its human readable content, e.g. for the top tree:

```
$ git ls-tree 0b6e66
100644 blob 887ae9333d92a1d72400c210546e28baa1050e44    file1  
040000 tree ab39965d17996be2116fe508faaf9269e903c85b    folder1
```

Each object ASCII SHA-1 hash is converted and stored in binary format. 
If what you need is just a binary version of the ASCII hashes, you can do it with:

```
$ echo -e "$(echo ASCIIHASH | sed -e 's/../\\x&/g')"
```

So the blob `887ae9333d92a1d72400c210546e28baa1050e44` is converted to

```
$ echo -e "$(echo 887ae9333d92a1d72400c210546e28baa1050e44 | sed -e 's/../\\x&/g')"
▒z▒3=▒▒▒$ ▒►Tn(▒▒♣D
```

If we want to create the whole tree object, here is an awk one-liner:

```
$ git ls-tree 0b6e66 | awk -b 'function bsha(asha)\
{patsplit(asha, x, /../); h=""; for(j in x) h=h sprintf("%c", strtonum("0x" x[j])); return(h)}\
{t=t sprintf("%d %s\0%s", $1, $4, bsha($3))} END {printf("tree %s\0%s", length(t), t)}'
tree 67 100644 file1 ▒z▒3=▒▒▒$ ▒►Tn(▒▒♣D40000 folder1 ▒9▒]▒k▒◄o▒▒▒i▒♥▒[%
```

The function `bsha` converts the SHA-1 ASCII hashes to binaries. The tree content is first put into the variable `t` and then its length is calculated and printed in the `END{...}` section.

As observed above, the console is not very suitable for printing binaries, so we might want to replace them with their `\x##` format equivalent:

```
$ git ls-tree 0b6e66 | awk -b 'function bsha(asha)\
{patsplit(asha, x, /../); h=""; for(j in x) h=h sprintf("%s", "\\x" x[j]); return(h)}\
{t=t sprintf("%d %s\0%s", $1, $4, bsha($3))} END {printf("tree %s\0%s", length(t), t)}'
tree 187 100644 file1 \x88\x7a\xe9\x33\x3d\x92\xa1\xd7\x24\x00\xc2\x10\x54\x6e\x28\xba\xa1\x05\x0e\x4440000 folder1 \xab\x39\x96\x5d\x17\x99\x6b\xe2\x11\x6f\xe5\x08\xfa\xaf\x92\x69\xe9\x03\xc8\x5b%
```

The output should be a good compromise for understanding the tree content structure. Compare the output above with the general tree content structure

```
tree [content size]\0[Object Entries]
```

where each Object Entry is like:

```
[mode] [Object name]\0[SHA-1 in binary format]
```

Modes are a subset of UNIX filesystem modes. See [Tree Objects](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects) on Git manual for more details.

We need to make sure that the results are consistent. To this end, we might  compare the checksum of the awk generated tree with the checksum  of the Git stored tree.

As for the latter:

```
$ openssl zlib -d -in .git/objects/0b/6e66b04bc1448ca594f143a91ec458667f420e | shasum
0b6e66b04bc1448ca594f143a91ec458667f420e *-
```

As for the home made tree:

```
$ git ls-tree 0b6e66 | awk -b 'function bsha(asha)\
{patsplit(asha, x, /../); h=""; for(j in x) h=h sprintf("%c", strtonum("0x" x[j])); return(h)}\
{t=t sprintf("%d %s\0%s", $1, $4, bsha($3))} END {printf("tree %s\0%s", length(t), t)}' | shasum
0b6e66b04bc1448ca594f143a91ec458667f420e *-
```

The checksum is the same.

#### Calculate the tree object checksum

The more or less official way to get it is:

```
$ git ls-tree 0b6e66 | git mktree
0b6e66b04bc1448ca594f143a91ec458667f420e
```

To calculate it manually, we need to pipe the content of the script generated tree into the `shasum` command.  Actually we have already done this above (to compare the generated and stored content). The results was:

```
0b6e66b04bc1448ca594f143a91ec458667f420e *-
```

and is  the same as with  `git mktree`.

#### Packed objects

You might find that, for your repo, you are unable to find the files 
`.git/objects/XX/XXX...` storing the Git objects. This happens because some or all "loose" objects have been packed into one or more `.git\objects\pack\*.pack` files.

To unpack the repo, first move the pack files away from their original position, then git-unpack  the objects.

```
$ mkdir .git/pcache   
$ mv .git/objects/pack/*.pack .git/pcache/     
$ git unpack-objects < .git/pcache/*.pack
```

To repack when you are done with experiments:

```
$ git gc
```

Comment: Why aren't the modes stored as binary?

Comment: @Random832: Probably because it would result in a minimal performance improvement  to the expense  of the clarity.

Comment: `OpenSSL 1.0.2o  27 Mar 2018`: `openssl:Error: 'zlib' is an invalid command.`  Which version are you using?

Comment: @Random832 Also zlib probably can do a great job of compressing modes, while the random hashes are both much longer and harder to compress (I guess they would require much larger dictionary compared to modes).

Answer (score 19):

Expressed as a BNF-like pattern, a git tree contains data of the form

```
(?<tree>  tree (?&SP) (?&decimal) \0 (?&entry)+ )
(?<entry> (?&octal) (?&SP) (?&strnull) (?&sha1bytes) )

(?<strnull>   [^\0]+ \0)
(?<sha1bytes> (?s: .{20}))
(?<decimal>   [0-9]+)
(?<octal>     [0-7]+)
(?<SP>        \x20)
```

That is, a git tree begins with a header of

1. the literal string `tree`
2. SPACE (*i.e.,* the byte `0x20`)
3. ASCII-encoded decimal length of the uncompressed contents

After a NUL (*i.e.*, the byte `0x00`) terminator, the tree contains one or more entries of the form

1. ASCII-encoded octal mode
2. SPACE
3. name
4. NUL
5. SHA1 hash encoded as 20 unsigned bytes

Git then feeds the tree data to [zlib’s](http://www.zlib.net/) deflate for compact storage.

Remember that git blobs are anonymous. Git trees associate names with SHA1 hashes of other content that may be blobs, other trees, and so on.

To demonstrate, consider the tree associated with git’s v2.7.2 tag, which you may want to [browse on GitHub](https://github.com/git/git/tree/326e5bc91eecf73234ead29636207bc516573e79).

```
$ git rev-parse v2.7.2^{tree}
802b6758c0c27ae910f40e1b4862cb72a71eee9f
```

The code below requires the tree object to be in “loose” format. I do not know of a way to extract a single raw object from a packfile, so I first ran [`git unpack-objects`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-unpack-objects.html) on the pack files from my clone to a new repository. Be aware that this expanded a `.git` directory that began around 90 MB to result of some 1.8 GB.

**UPDATE:** Thanks to max630 for showing [how to unpack a single object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35909341/123109).

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use subs qw/ git_tree_contents_pattern read_raw_tree_object /;

use Compress::Zlib;

my $treeobj = read_raw_tree_object;

my $git_tree_contents = git_tree_contents_pattern;
die "$0: invalid tree" unless $treeobj =~ /^$git_tree_contents\z/;

die "$0: unexpected header" unless $treeobj =~ s/^(tree [0-9]+)\0//;
print $1, "\n";

# e.g., 100644 SP .gitattributes \0 sha1-bytes
while ($treeobj) {
  # /s is important so . matches any byte!
  if ($treeobj =~ s/^([0-7]+) (.+?)\0(.{20})//s) {
    my($mode,$name,$bytes) = (oct($1),$2,$3);
    printf "%06o %s %s\t%s\n",
      $mode, ($mode == 040000 ? "tree" : "blob"),
      unpack("H*", $bytes), $name;
  }
  else {
    die "$0: unexpected tree entry";
  }
}

sub git_tree_contents_pattern {
  qr/
  (?(DEFINE)
    (?<tree>  tree (?&SP) (?&decimal) \0 (?&entry)+ )
    (?<entry> (?&octal) (?&SP) (?&strnull) (?&sha1bytes) )

    (?<strnull>   [^\0]+ \0)
    (?<sha1bytes> (?s: .{20}))
    (?<decimal>   [0-9]+)
    (?<octal>     [0-7]+)
    (?<SP>        \x20)
  )

  (?&tree)
  /x;
}

sub read_raw_tree_object {
  # $ git rev-parse v2.7.2^{tree}
  # 802b6758c0c27ae910f40e1b4862cb72a71eee9f
  #
  # NOTE: extracted using git unpack-objects
  my $tree = ".git/objects/80/2b6758c0c27ae910f40e1b4862cb72a71eee9f";

  open my $fh, "<", $tree or die "$0: open $tree: $!";
  binmode $fh or die "$0: binmode: $!";
  local $/;
  my $treeobj = uncompress <$fh>;
  die "$0: uncompress failed" unless defined $treeobj;

  $treeobj
}
```

Watch our poor man’s `git ls-tree` in action. The output is identical except that it outputs the `tree` marker and length.

```
$ diff -u <(cd ~/src/git; git ls-tree 802b6758c0) <(../rawtree)
--- /dev/fd/63  2016-03-09 14:41:37.011791393 -0600
+++ /dev/fd/62  2016-03-09 14:41:37.011791393 -0600
@@ -1,3 +1,4 @@
+tree 15530
 100644 blob 5e98806c6cc246acef5f539ae191710a0c06ad3f   .gitattributes
 100644 blob 1c2f8321386f89ef8c03d11159c97a0f194c4423   .gitignore
 100644 blob e5b4126bec557db55924b7b60ed70349626ea2c4   .mailmap
```

Comment: See also the [“Tree” section in “Reimplementing ‘git clone’ in Haskell from the bottom up”](http://stefan.saasen.me/articles/git-clone-in-haskell-from-the-bottom-up/#tree) for a reasonable high-level sketch.

Answer (score 4):

As suggested, Pro Git explains the structure well. To show a tree pretty-printed, use:

```
git cat-file -p 4c975c5f5945564eae86d1e933192c4a9096bfe5
```

to show the same tree in its raw, but uncompressed form, use:

```
git cat-file tree 4c975c5f5945564eae86d1e933192c4a9096bfe5
```

The structure is essentially the same, with hashes stored as binary and null-terminated filenames.

Comment: This doesn’t tell about the uncompressed binary structure.

Comment: @user2284570 "Pro Git explains the structure well." Well worth a look.

Comment: Ok, I got it, my problem is to`printf()`a string in C containing null bytes.

Answer (score 4):

@lemiorhan answer is correct but misses small important detail.
Tree format is:

```
[mode] [file/folder name]\0[SHA-1 of referencing blob or tree]
```

But what is important is that `[SHA-1 of referencing blob or tree]` is in binary form, not in hex. This is Python snippet to parse tree object into entries:

```py
entries = [
   line[0:2]+(line[2].encode('hex'),)
   for line in
   re.findall('(\d+) (.*?)\0(.{20})', body, re.MULTILINE)
]
```