# Git plumbing: export tree at commit without touching HEAD/index

Tags: git, git-plumbing

I'm writing a program that needs to concurrently extract different commits from the same repository (like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160608/do-a-git-export-like-svn-export), but concurrently).

Porcelain commands such as `git checkout` and `git archive` operate on the index, thus any time a commit would need to be extracted, it would need to move HEAD and/or go through the index first.

Is there a simple way to just dump a Git tree object into a directory on the filesystem?

Comment: `git archive` does not operate on the index, and does not require modifications to HEAD, index or working directory. `git archive -o /tmp/somefile.tar sha1-of-old-commit` is probably what you want. A tag, branch name, or other form of ref (e.g. `dev@{3 days ago}`) is equally appropriate for the sha1 argument.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it programmatically is to use [`git cat-file`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-cat-file).

When started in batch mode (`--batch`), you can feed commit IDs to its standard input, and it will immediately dump the object to standard output (incl. a header to indicate the object type and length). You can thus traverse the commit's tree object recursively by spawning a `git cat-file` process, writing object (blob and sub-tree) SHAs to its standard input, writing blobs to disk, and recursing for tree objects.

Note that the tree objects will be dumped in binary format; you can find a description of the format in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21599232/21501).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `git archive` to export a `tar` archive of a particular commit, and immediately extract it to some target directory:

```
git archive <commit> | tar -xf - -C <output-directory>
```

This will also work for *any* tree object, instead of `<commit>`.