# How is the Git hash calculated?

Tags: git, hash

I'm trying to understand how Git calculates the hash of refs.

```
$ git ls-remote https://github.com/git/git  

....
29932f3915935d773dc8d52c292cadd81c81071d    refs/tags/v2.4.2
9eabf5b536662000f79978c4d1b6e4eff5c8d785    refs/tags/v2.4.2^{}
....
```

Clone the repo locally. Check the `refs/tags/v2.4.2^{}` ref by sha

```
$ git cat-file -p 9eabf5b536662000f79978c4d1b6e4eff5c8d785 

tree 655a20f99af32926cbf6d8fab092506ddd70e49c
parent df08eb357dd7f432c3dcbe0ef4b3212a38b4aeff
author Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com> 1432673399 -0700
committer Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com> 1432673399 -0700

Git 2.4.2

Signed-off-by: Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com>
```

Copy the decompressed content so that we can hash it. (AFAIK Git uses the uncompressed version when it's hashing)

```
git cat-file -p 9eabf5b536662000f79978c4d1b6e4eff5c8d785 > fi
```

Let's SHA-1 the content using Git's own hash command

```
git hash-object fi
3cf741bbdbcdeed65e5371912742e854a035e665
```

Why is the output not `[9e]abf5b536662000f79978c4d1b6e4eff5c8d785`? I understand the first two characters (`9e`) are the length in hex. How should I hash the content of `fi` so that I can get the Git ref `abf5b536662000f79978c4d1b6e4eff5c8d785`?

Comment: (1) `git hash-object` is adding files, not other object types. Obviously type is appended to hashed content somehow. And I bet 9e is not length, the whole line is a hash as sha1 algorithm returns it.

Comment: `SHA=9eabf5b536662000f79978c4d1b6e4eff5c8d785; git cat-file -p $SHA | git hash-object -t $(git cat-file -t $SHA) --stdin`.  Read: You need `git hash-object -t commit fi`

Answer (score 39, accepted):

As described in "[How is git commit sha1 formed](https://gist.github.com/masak/2415865) ", the formula is:

```
(printf "<type> %s\0" $(git cat-file <type> <ref> | wc -c); git cat-file <type> <ref>)|sha1sum
```

In the case of the **commit** 9eabf5b536662000f79978c4d1b6e4eff5c8d785 (which is `v2.4.2^{}`, and which referenced a tree) :

```
(printf "commit %s\0" $(git cat-file commit 9eabf5b536662000f79978c4d1b6e4eff5c8d785 | wc -c); git cat-file commit 9eabf5b536662000f79978c4d1b6e4eff5c8d785 )|sha1sum
```

That will give 9eabf5b536662000f79978c4d1b6e4eff5c8d785.

As would:

```
(printf "commit %s\0" $(git cat-file commit v2.4.2{} | wc -c); git cat-file commit v2.4.2{})|sha1sum
```

(still 9eabf5b536662000f79978c4d1b6e4eff5c8d785)

Similarly, computing the SHA1 of the tag v2.4.2 would be:

```
(printf "tag %s\0" $(git cat-file tag v2.4.2 | wc -c); git cat-file tag v2.4.2)|sha1sum
```

That would give 29932f3915935d773dc8d52c292cadd81c81071d.

Comment: I'm not sure why but I get different data $  `(printf "tree %s\0" $(git cat-file tree 9eabf5b536662000f79978c4d1b6e4eff5c8d785 | wc -c); git cat-file tree 9eabf5b536662000f79978c4d1b6e4eff5c8d785 )|sha1sum
655a20f99af32926cbf6d8fab092506ddd70e49c `

Comment: You mixed commit and tree: use the same type

Comment: Then you have to get the same sha1. Does it work when using the dereferenced tag? v2.4.2{}

Comment: I think the issue is due using <type> and `tree` . This works (using -pretty and commit). Any idea why it works using commit if it's a 'tree' ?  `(printf "commit %s\0" $(git cat-file -p  9eabf5b536662000f79978c4d1b6e4eff5c8d785 | wc -c); git cat-file -p 9eabf5b536662000f79978c4d1b6e4eff5c8d785 )|sha1sum
9eabf5b536662000f79978c4d1b6e4eff5c8d785 `

Comment: @Theuserwithnohat My fault: I tested it in my repo and it worked indeed with commit (which, in your case, referenced the tree 655a20f99af32926cbf6d8fab092506ddd70e49c). I have updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 37):

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ronoCeMzfJ4) by John Williams gives an overview of what data goes into the calculation of a Git commit hash. Here's a screenshot from the video:

[image: Git tree]

## Reimplementing the commit hash without Git

To get a deeper understanding of this aspect of Git, I reimplemented the steps that produce a Git commit hash in Rust, without using Git. It currently works for getting the hash *when committing a single file*. The answers here were helpful in achieving this, thanks.

The source code of this answer is available [here](https://gitlab.com/bullbytes/git-commit-hash). Execute it with `cargo run`.

These are the individual pieces of data we need to compute to arrive at a Git commit hash:

1. The **object ID** of the file, which involves hashing the file contents with SHA-1. In Git, [`hash-object`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-hash-object) provides this ID.
2. The **object entries** that go into the tree object. In Git, you can get an idea of those entries with [`ls-tree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-tree), but their format in the tree object is slightly different: `[mode] [file name]\0[object ID]`
3. The **hash of the tree object** which has the form: `tree [size of object entries]\0[object entries]`. In Git, get the tree hash with: `git cat-file commit HEAD | head -n1`
4. The **commit hash** by hashing the data you see with [`cat-file`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cat-file). This includes the tree object hash and commit information like author, time, commit message, and the parent commit hash if it's not the first commit.

Each step depends on the previous one. Let's start with the first.

### Get the object ID of the file

The first step is to reimplement Git's [`hash-object`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-hash-object), as in `git hash-object your_file`.

We create the object hash from our file by concatenating and hashing these data:

- The string "blob " at the beginning (mind the trailing space), followed by
- the number of bytes in the file, followed by
- a null byte, expressed with `\0` in `printf` and Rust, followed by
- the file content.

In Bash:

```bash
file_name="your_file";
printf "blob $(wc -c < "$file_name")\0$(cat "$file_name")" | sha1sum
```

In Rust:

```rust
// Get the object ID
fn git_hash_object(file_content: &[u8]) -> Vec<u8> {
    let file_size = file_content.len().to_string();
    let hash_input = [
        "blob ".as_bytes(),
        file_size.as_bytes(),
        b"\0",
        file_content,
    ]
    .concat();
    to_sha1(&hash_input)
}
```

I'm using [crate sha1](https://docs.rs/sha1/0.10.5/sha1/) version 0.10.5 in `to_sha1`:

```rust
fn to_sha1(hash_me: &[u8]) -> Vec<u8> {
    use sha1::{Digest, Sha1};

    let mut hasher = Sha1::new();
    hasher.update(hash_me);
    hasher.finalize().to_vec()
}
```

### Get the object entry of the file

Object entries are part of Git's [tree object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790681/what-is-the-internal-format-of-a-git-tree-object#21599232). Tree objects represent files and directories.

Object entries for files have this form: `[mode] [file name]\0[object ID]`

We assume the file is a regular, non-executable file, which translates to mode 100644 in Git. See [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/450480/file-permission-with-six-bytes-in-git-what-does-it-mean) for more on modes.

This Rust function takes the result of the previous function `git_hash_object` as the parameter `object_id`:

```rust
fn object_entry(file_name: &str, object_id: &[u8]) -> Vec<u8> {
    // It's a regular, non-executable file
    let mode = "100644";

    // [mode] [file name]\0[object ID]
    let object_entry = [
        mode.as_bytes(),
        b" ",
        file_name.as_bytes(),
        b"\0",
        object_id,
    ]
    .concat();

    object_entry
}
```

I tried to write the equivalent of `object_entry` in Bash, but Bash variables [cannot contain null bytes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/174016/how-do-i-use-null-bytes-in-bash). There are probably ways around that limitation, but I decided for now that if I can't have variables in Bash, the code would get quite difficult to understand. Edits providing a readable Bash equivalent are welcome.

### Get the tree object hash

As mentioned above, tree objects represent files and directories in Git. You can see the hash of your tree object by running, for example, `git cat-file commit HEAD | head -n1`.

The tree object has this form: `tree [size of object entries]\0[object entries]`

In our case we only have a single `object_entry`, calculated in the previous step:

```rust
fn tree_object_hash(object_entry: &[u8]) -> String {
    let object_entry_size = object_entry.len().to_string();

    let tree_object = [
        "tree ".as_bytes(),
        object_entry_size.as_bytes(),
        b"\0",
        object_entry,
    ]
    .concat();

    to_hex_str(&to_sha1(&tree_object))
}
```

Where `to_hex_str` is defined as:

```rust
// Converts bytes to their hexadecimal representation.
fn to_hex_str(bytes: &[u8]) -> String {
    bytes.iter().map(|byte| format!("{byte:02x}")).collect()
}
```

In a Git repo, you can look at the contents of the tree object with [`ls-tree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-tree). For example, running `git ls-tree HEAD` will produce lines like these:

```
100644 blob b8c0d74ef5ccd3dab583add7b3f5367efe4bf823    your_file
```

While those lines contain the data of an object entry (the mode, the object ID, and the file name), they are in a different order and include a tab character as well as the string "blob" which is input to the object ID, not the object entry. Object entries have this form: `[mode] [file name]\0[object ID]`

### Get the commit hash

The last step creates the commit hash.

The data we hash using SHA-1 includes:

- Tree object hash from the previous step.
- Hash of the parent commit if the commit is not the very first one in the repo.
- Author name and authoring date.
- Committer name and committing date.
- Commit message.

You can see all of that data with `git cat-file commit HEAD`, for example:

```
tree a76b2df314b47956268b0c39c88a3b2365fb87eb
parent 9881a96ab93a3493c4f5002f17b4a1ba3308b58b
author Matthias Braun <m.braun@example.com> 1625338354 +0200
committer Matthias Braun <m.braun@example.com> 1625338354 +0200

Second commit (that's the commit message)
```

You might have guessed that `1625338354` is a timestamp. In this case it's the number of seconds since the [Unix epoch](https://www.epochconverter.com/). You can convert from the date and time format of `git log`, such as "Sat Jul 3 20:52:34 2021", to Unix epoch seconds with [`date`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html):

```bash
date --date='Sat Jul 3 20:52:34 2021' +"%s"
```

The time zone is denoted as `+0200` in this example.

Based on the output of `cat-file`, you can create the Git commit hash using this Bash command (which uses `git cat-file`, so it's no reimplementation):

```bash
cat_file_output=$(git cat-file commit HEAD);
printf "commit $(wc -c <<< "$cat_file_output")\0$cat_file_output\n" | sha1sum
```

The Bash command illustrates that—similar to the steps before—what we hash is:

- A leading string, "commit " in this step, followed by
- the size of a bunch of data. Here it's the output of `cat-file` which is detailed above. Followed by
- a null byte, followed by
- the data itself (output of `cat-file`) with a line break at the end.

In case you kept score: Creating a Git commit hash involves using SHA-1 at least three times.

Below is the Rust function for creating the Git commit hash. It uses the `tree_object_hash` produced in the previous step and a struct `CommitMetaData` which contains the rest of the data you see when calling `git cat-file commit HEAD`. The function also takes care of whether the commit has a parent commit or not.

```rust
fn commit_hash(commit: &CommitMetaData, tree_object_hash: &str) -> Vec<u8> {
    let author_line = format!(
        "{} {}",
        commit.author_name_and_email, commit.author_timestamp_and_timezone
    );
    let committer_line = format!(
        "{} {}",
        commit.committer_name_and_email, commit.committer_timestamp_and_timezone
    );

    // If it's the first commit, which has no parent,
    // the line starting with "parent" is omitted
    let parent_commit_line = match commit.parent_commit_hash {
        Some(parent_commit_hash) => format!("\nparent {parent_commit_hash}"),
        None => "".to_string(),
    };
    let git_cat_file_str = format!(
        "tree {}{}\nauthor {}\ncommitter {}\n\n{}\n",
        tree_object_hash, parent_commit_line, author_line, committer_line, commit.commit_message
    );

    let git_cat_file_len = git_cat_file_str.len().to_string();

    let commit_object = [
        "commit ".as_bytes(),
        git_cat_file_len.as_bytes(),
        b"\0",
        git_cat_file_str.as_bytes(),
    ]
    .concat();

    // Return the Git commit hash
    to_sha1(&commit_object)
}
```

Here's `CommitMetaData`:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone)]
pub struct CommitMetaData<'a> {
    pub(crate) author_name_and_email: &'a str,
    pub(crate) author_timestamp_and_timezone: &'a str,
    pub(crate) committer_name_and_email: &'a str,
    pub(crate) committer_timestamp_and_timezone: &'a str,
    pub(crate) commit_message: &'a str,
    // All commits after the first one have a parent commit
    pub(crate) parent_commit_hash: Option<&'a str>,
}
```

This function creates `CommitMetaData` where author and committer info are identical, which will be convenient when we run the program later:

```rust
pub fn simple_commit<'a>(
    author_name_and_email: &'a str,
    author_timestamp_and_timezone: &'a str,
    commit_message: &'a str,
    parent_commit_hash: Option<&'a str>,
) -> CommitMetaData<'a> {
    CommitMetaData {
        author_name_and_email,
        author_timestamp_and_timezone,
        committer_name_and_email: author_name_and_email,
        committer_timestamp_and_timezone: author_timestamp_and_timezone,
        commit_message,
        parent_commit_hash,
    }
}
```

### Putting it all together

As a summary and reminder, creating a Git commit hash consists of getting:

1. The **object ID** of the file, which involves hashing the file contents with SHA-1. In Git, [`hash-object`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-hash-object) provides this ID.
2. The **object entries** that go into the tree object. In Git, you can get an idea of those entries with [`ls-tree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-tree), but their format in the tree object is slightly different: `[mode] [file name]\0[object ID]`
3. The **hash of the tree object** which has the form: `tree [size of object entries]\0[object entries]`. In Git, get the tree hash with: `git cat-file commit HEAD | head -n1`
4. The **commit hash** by hashing the data you see with [`cat-file`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cat-file). This includes the tree object hash and commit information like author, time, commit message, and the parent commit hash if it's not the first commit.

In Rust:

```rust
pub fn get_commit_hash(
    file_name: &str,
    file_content: &[u8],
    commit: &CommitMetaData
) -> String {
    let file_object_id = git_hash_object(file_content);
    let object_entry = object_entry(file_name, &file_object_id);
    let tree_object_hash = tree_object_hash(&object_entry);

    let commit_hash = commit_hash(commit, &tree_object_hash);
    to_hex_str(&commit_hash)
}
```

With the functions above, you can create a file's Git commit hash in Rust, without Git:

```rust
use std::{fs, io};

fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
    let file_name = "your_file";
    let file_content = fs::read(file_name)?;

    let first_commit = simple_commit(
        "Firstname Lastname <test@example.com>",
        // Timestamp calculated using: date --date='Wed Jun 23 18:02:18 2021' +"%s"
        "1624464138 +0200",
        "Message of first commit",
        // No parent commit hash since this is the first commit
        None,
    );

    let first_commit_hash = get_commit_hash(file_name, &file_content, &first_commit);
    Ok(println!("Git commit hash: {first_commit_hash}"))
}
```

To create the hash of the second commit, you take the hash of the first commit and put it into the `CommitMetaData` of the second commit:

```rust
let second_commit = simple_commit(
    "Firstname Lastname <test@example.com>",
    "1625388354 +0200",
    "Message of second commit",
    // The first commit is the parent of the second commit
    Some(first_commit_hash),
);
```

---

Apart from the other answers here and their links, these were some useful resources in creating my limited reimplementation:

- [Reimplementation](https://github.com/Richienb/git-hash-object/blob/master/index.js) of `git hash-object` in JavaScript.
- [Format of a Git tree object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790681/what-is-the-internal-format-of-a-git-tree-object), this is the next place I'd look if I wanted to make my reimplementation more complete: To work with commits involving more than one file.

Comment: You mentioned that tree size is calculated by the size of the object entries. By that you litteraly mean the sum of all the objects characters? For example, if a tree has two objects which header is blob 10\0, then the tree size would be 20?

Comment: You'd sum the bytes of each object entry not the file sizes. Note that I haven't tested that, I only implemented it for a single object entry. "if a tree has two objects which header is blob 10\0, then the tree size would be 20?" I don't think so, since each object entry has the format `[mode] [file name]\0[object ID]` and the number after "blob" refers to the file size which is part of the data that gets hashed to become the object ID.

Answer (score 12):

There's bit of confusion here. Git uses different types of objects: blobs, trees and commits.
The following command:

```
git cat-file -t <hash>
```

Tells you the type of object for a given hash.
So in your example, the hash 9eabf5b536662000f79978c4d1b6e4eff5c8d785 corresponds to a commit object.

Now, as you figured out yourself, running this:

```
git cat-file -p 9eabf5b536662000f79978c4d1b6e4eff5c8d785
```

Gives you the content of the object according to its type (in this instance, a commit).

But, this:

```
git hash-object fi
```

...computes the hash for a blob whose content is the output of the previous command (in your example), but it could be anything else (like "hello world!"). Here try this:

```
echo "blob 277\0$(cat fi)" | shasum
```

The output is the same as the previous command. This is basically how Git hashes a blob. So by hashing fi,  you are generating a blob object. But as we have seen, 9eabf5b536662000f79978c4d1b6e4eff5c8d785 is a commit, not a blob. So, you cannot hash fi as it is in order to get the same hash.

A commit's hash is based on several other informations which makes it unique (such as the committer, the author, the date, etc). The following article tells you exactly what a commit hash is made of:

[The anatomy of a git commit](http://blog.thoughtram.io/git/2014/11/18/the-anatomy-of-a-git-commit.html)

So you could get the same hash by providing all the data specified in the article with the exact same values as those used in the original commit.

This might be helpful as well:

[Git from the bottom up](http://ftp.newartisans.com/pub/git.from.bottom.up.pdf)

Comment: `echo "blob 277\0$(cat fi)" | shasum` produced different results than `git hash-object fi` for me for two reasons: First, I didn't know that 277 refers to the size of `fi` and the size of my particular `fi` is not equal to 277. Second, the GNU coreutils version of `echo` adds a newline and doesn't escape `\0` to mean the NUL byte (`echo -en` fixes this). The following command produces the same result as `git hash-object fi`: `printf "blob $(wc -c < fi)\0$(cat fi)" | sha1sum`.

Comment: So it is "blob ${filesizeinbytes}\0${filecontent}". This command worked fine in th git bash under windows: `stat --printf="blob %s\0" $FILENAME | cat - $FILENAME | sha1sum`.