# Manually create a new file in a .patch file, but what is the "index" line for?

Tags: linux, git, command-line, patch

[image]

I generated a patch file using git, but now I want to manually add in a new file into the patch. Its just a text file with one line. I copied another section of the patch file that creates a new file, but I don't know what to put for the line that says "index". See my screen shot. I'm guessing its a hash of the new file? Is this index line necessary?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+diff+file+format

Comment: Therere 2 hashes (`0000000` for old hash means it's a new file) and file mode.

Comment: it doesn't answer my question. do i need the index line or not? what do i put there if i'm just creating a blank file in the patch?

Comment: Blank file has a hash.

Comment: so the line should look like: **index 0000000..0000000** ?

Comment: SHA1 hashes are [calculated in Git for database objects which have headers and data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35433095/7976758) (https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+calculate+hash). An empty file is stored in the DB as blob with header `blob 0\0` (first `0` is file length, `\0` is NULL that separates headers from data) and no data. The hash for the blob of the empty file is `echo -en 'blob 0\0' | sha1sum` -> `e69de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391`. So the line should look like `index 0000000..e69de29 100644`