# Git: getting a commit hash in advance before actually committing

Tags: git

I'd like to get a git hash of the current repo state **with** some changes present but **without** actually committing anything. In other words, is there a way to know in advance what the hash **would** look like **if** the changes got commited at some point later? We can assume that the commit messages are going to be the same.

Comment: Why not commit the changes? Relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35430584/how-is-the-git-hash-calculated?

Comment: @evolutionxbox If that were an option, I wouldn't post on SO :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, this is not possible, because the commit object contains both an author and committer identifier and timestamp.  As a consequence, the hash of the object is dependent on the time it was created and who created it, so there are many possible commit hashes depending on when the commit actually gets created.

If the commit is being signed, the signature will also create a timestamp, and it's also possible that the signature may contain random data, depending on the algorithm and version of GnuPG, so the actual value may end up being unknowable ahead of time.

If you want to know the *root tree* hash, then that's easier.  You can add the desired changes to the index and run `git write-tree`.  That *will* create a tree object and print its hash to standard output, but it's otherwise unreferenced, so if you never actually end up using it, it'll be pruned eventually.  You can even set `GIT_INDEX_FILE` to a temporary file and then run `git add` to add to a temporary index and then run `git write-tree`, which will use that temporary index file.

If you really want to know without creating any objects in the repository, then you'll need to use something like libgit2 to do that.