# Is it possible to create cross directory hard links in git?

Tags: git, security, math, sha1, denial-of-service

git builds and stores paths in ram. It means if a directory can reference it’s parent with a regular name, the server or the client computer which clone a repository will run out of ram *(no code seems to check that)*.

However paths are stored in git trees. [Given the structure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21599232/2284570), it seems including a reference to a parent tree object will modify the sha1 of that parent.
Is there a way to solve that math/recursive sha1 problem ?

Comment: Well, you can always brute force it.  Dang, where's my :trollface: emoji when I need it!?!

Comment: @EdwardThomson : I can’t even see a bruteforce way that can solve this theoretically.