# How do I unpack a single git object?

Tags: git

In an [answer to a question about the internal format of git’s tree objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35902553/123109), to get to one particular tree object that was stored in a pack, I unpacked all of the objects in a repository’s packfiles using [`git unpack-objects`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-unpack-objects.html). That seems like overkill. Yes, I realize that commands such `git show --raw`, `git ls-tree`, or `git cat-file` will get *close* to the internal format.

How do I make git output a single object in its internal format — complete with `blob`, `tree`, `commit`, or `tag` header — regardless of whether it is stored in loose or packed format?

Comment: You can just zlib decompress it with `zpipe -d < <object>` from within `.git/objects`

Comment: @AndrewC Yes, if it’s already a loose object, but what if it lives in a pack?

Comment: Greg I thought the premise of your question was that you had unpacked the objects  and had a loose object.  I don't know the answer to doing it from a pack file except to unpack it first.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [git pack-objects](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-pack-objects.html) first to make a pack with only this one object.

Note also that git unpack-objects does not extract objects which already exist in a repository, so you probably want to make a new repository. Overall something like this should work:

```
$ DIR=$(mktemp -d)
$ echo 5e98806c6cc246acef5f539ae191710a0c06ad3f \
   | git pack-objects --stdout \
   | ( cd "$DIR" && git init && git unpack-objects )
```

Then look for your unpacked object in `$DIR/.git/objects`