# Git/GitKraken – File Mode changes to unknown value (14001) after restoring repo from backup

Tags: git, permissions, chmod, octal, gitkraken

Still new to Git(Kraken). Had a logic board go bad on me, and had to restore a repo from a backup, reinstall software, and get back up and running on a temporary machine till I can get the original back from the shop.

Now I have the repo open in Gitkraken, which is telling me I have 2,224 file changes on my hotfix branch – apparently *all* files. If I click on any one of them, the Diff View panel displays the messages, "File Mode Changes from 217 to 14001" and "File contents are unchanged."

I was able to translate the 217 Octal Value on file permissions.com, but found nothing for 14001.

I'm no expert on file permissions, but 217 (presumably the default setting on my prior machine, as I don't recall changing it) appears to be less than ideal, with only write access for User, execute access for Group, and full access for Other.

Can anyone tell me what this 14001 setting is all about (this is a brand new MacBook Pro, vs. the 2015 model that's being fixed)? Is this setting preferable to 217 (it would almost have to be...?)? What settings are ideal for static website files, and would it be good/bad/neutral to push these file mode changes?

Comment: what file system is your backup using?

Comment: Good question... old computer ran El Capitan, new computer runs High Sierra ( (APFS/Apple File System, apparently a newer proprietary file system for macOS High Sierra and later). Files were backed up to/downloaded from Backblaze.

Comment: I had the same diff occur on a Ubuntu 18.10 ext4 filesystem randomly. Would be interesting to see what causes this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution I found was to delete the local instance of the repo and to reclone it from the source repo. This avoids the altered permissions issue entirely.

Answer (score 10):

I had the exact same problem where GitKraken shows "File Mode Changes from 217 to 14001." My teammate ran some command with `sudo` which changed the file modes. It may be a GitKraken bug – if you use `git show -p <commit_hash>` you'll see the actual change was " changed file mode from 100644 to 100755."

The permission 644 is `-rw-r--r--`, and 755 is `-rwxr-xr-x`. You'd want to keep the permissions as 644 as most files should not be executable.

You can either revert the commit, or use `chmod` stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11512211/9527593).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue also. For https://github.com/seL4/sel4bench-manifest/commit/04b59e4e08670ba1f5f149f76e3aa3dbebc3fa13 GitKraken v7.6.1 says for `default.xml` that "File Mode Changes from 217 to 217" in the diff view. Since no other GIT tool shows any issues here, I've reported this as a bug in GitKraken. Let's see what comes back.

Comment: And the same now for ssh://git@github.com/seL4/camkes-manifest.git and `default.xml`.

Comment: Problem reported here also without a real solution: https://devrant.com/rants/2302242/dear-git-why-are-you-lying-theres-no-changes-in-that-file-you-say-that-yourself

Comment: MYSTERY RESOLVED! See https://github.com/seL4/camkes-manifest/pull/10 for the explanation, credits also go to  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790681/what-is-the-internal-format-of-a-git-tree-object that allows seeing the git internals. Recommendation to the GitKraken guys is, don't report this diff in the GUI, it's an internal thing to handle legacy.