# Migration from linux to mac shows change in file mode in git

Tags: linux, git, macos

I moved over an entire repo from linux (Ubuntu) to mac os 10.14, git shows 265 files unchanged except for `File Mode changes from 217 to 14001`, I am able to pull/push and what not with git, just not sure what to do with these changes.
what does this mean?
What will happen if I simply discard these changes?
Should I commit these changes?

Comment: Can you explain why the files had mode `217` in the first place?  Seems like a strange filemode.

Comment: No idea, it was just a cloned repo, never even heard of filemode until now. Apparently it has to do with file permissions

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53399046/git-gitkraken-file-mode-changes-to-unknown-value-14001-after-restoring-repo)?

Comment: @trojanfoe just saw this, seems like what I have although the accepted answer wouldn't work for me since I am NOT looking to clone the repo from the source as I have many local branches that dont exist on the source and cannot push them to the source.

Comment: How did you move the repo? Maybe you should create a `tar` archive on the Linux system, move this to the Mac and extract it there.

Comment: I copied it onto a disk-on-key, I can do your suggestion, will that somehow change the file permissions?