# Getting SHA hash of file in specific commit

Tags: git

How can I get SHA hash of a file in specified commit? I can get all commits that touched the file using `git log file`, but how can I get SHA hash of a file in each particular commit?

I think I can do it by checking out the commit and than use `git-hash-object`, but there must be easier way.

Comment: Do you need the verbatim SHA1 of the file contents only, or do you want the SHA1 of the blob object used to store the file in Git's history?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the blob object includes file mode and stuff? If that's the difference, I need the file contents only, like if I would run `sha1sum file`.

Comment: The blob contains additional type and length information and some null bytes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`git show` and `git log` are close cousins and share options. Your question asked about the SHA-1 object name of a file associated with a particular commit but then also for the same information for each commit along the way in the history.

The `--raw` option gives the information you’re after. The examples below will use git’s own repository.

To show the files that changed with a particular commit, use `git show` or `git log -1`. The latter will not generate output for the tag object but the tagged commit only.

```
$ git log -1 --raw v2.8.1
commit d95553a6b8c5153f541adcfc3346004e8249b0e6
Author: Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com>
Date:   Sun Apr 3 10:11:35 2016 -0700

    Git 2.8.1

    Signed-off-by: Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com>

:000000 100644 0000000... ef6d80b... A  Documentation/RelNotes/2.8.1.txt
:100644 100644 adc940b... 8afe349... M  Documentation/git.txt
:100755 100755 4e9450b... 46595da... M  GIT-VERSION-GEN
:120000 120000 7db3040... d40c3e1... M  RelNotes
```

Each change line contains

- beginning or source mode (`000000` indicates created or unmerged)
- resulting or destination mode (`000000` indicates deleted or unmerged)
- source SHA-1 (all zeros for creation)
- destination SHA-1 (all zeros for deletion)
- status code plus optional numeric score (above `A` is addition and `M` modification)
- path

See [“Raw output format” in `git diff`’s documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#_raw_output_format) for the full details.

The SHA-1 object name for the file `RelNotes` associated with the v2.8.1 tag is d40c3e1, which we can verify and expand to all forty digits with

```
$ git rev-parse v2.8.1:RelNotes
d40c3e126c03b0e4bd9c6162f63a35a45f5e9020
```

To show hashes for `RelNotes`, which is a symbolic link that points to the under `Documentation/RelNotes` that corresponds to a given version, along the way in version 2.8.1’s history:

```
$ git log --raw v2.8.1 -- RelNotes
commit d95553a6b8c5153f541adcfc3346004e8249b0e6
Author: Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com>
Date:   Sun Apr 3 10:11:35 2016 -0700

    Git 2.8.1

    Signed-off-by: Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com>

:120000 120000 7db3040... d40c3e1... M  RelNotes

commit c9906e47c065940bfe1a9992da494a8f437a49ac
Author: Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com>
Date:   Tue Jan 12 15:20:51 2016 -0800

    First batch for post 2.7 cycle

    Signed-off-by: Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com>

:120000 120000 3ba13ce... 7db3040... M  RelNotes

commit 24a00ef646974be49ef7138239c3803805400797
Author: Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com>
Date:   Mon Oct 5 12:58:10 2015 -0700

    Start cycle toward 2.7

    Signed-off-by: Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com>

:120000 120000 def6ebd... 3ba13ce... M  RelNotes
[...]
```

Use the `--abbrev` option to get all forty hex digits of the hash. Here the output will appear extra chatty because the output of `git show` covers both the v2.8.1 tag and the commit to which `v2.8.1` points.

```
$ git show --raw --abbrev=40 v2.8.1
tag v2.8.1
Tagger: Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com>
Date:   Sun Apr 3 10:14:32 2016 -0700

Git 2.8.1
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----
Version: GnuPG v1
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=NLvn
-----END PGP SIGNATURE-----

commit d95553a6b8c5153f541adcfc3346004e8249b0e6
Author: Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com>
Date:   Sun Apr 3 10:11:35 2016 -0700

    Git 2.8.1

    Signed-off-by: Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com>

:000000 100644 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 ef6d80b008a0a7970238404b034593be27e933c3 A      Documentation/RelNotes/2.8.1.txt
:100644 100644 adc940bf7591069c74c9b47aa5e5686e0438d606 8afe349781d57527083fdb75511959fd25a4239b M      Documentation/git.txt
:100755 100755 4e9450b3ae0c403820f0166435c52c4ea74e7451 46595dad2234f861198347ef8f4f60d167061709 M      GIT-VERSION-GEN
:120000 120000 7db30403c3471e15f4f15a5e68016d7926b3e3de d40c3e126c03b0e4bd9c6162f63a35a45f5e9020 M      RelNotes
```

The SHA-1 object name of a blob (how git represents file contents) is not identical to running `sha1sum` on the file because git adds metadata to the front: the literal string `blob`, followed by a space, followed by the length of the content in decimal, and terminated with a NUL byte. To compute a SHA-1 hash of the contents of successive versions of a file going backward in time, use a command along the lines of

```
$ for commit in $(git log --pretty=%H v2.8.1 -- RelNotes | head -3) ; \
    do git show ${commit}:RelNotes | sha1sum ; \
  done
ce5501f9daadf110a20a4e4eccdfed63ef4b27e3  -
bd4d920214c4a48d8820292e24f020690595858d  -
5d47b511d86abd490fa4f2c2a8d4ef3589e1aecf  -
```

With `--pretty=%H` and `-- RelNotes` we tell git that we want only the SHA-1 hashes of commits that touch `RelNotes` (limited to the three most recent with `head -3`). Then for each of those commits, we feed the tracked content to `sha1sum`.

If you prefer `xargs`, it looks like

```
$ git log --pretty=%H v2.8.1 -- RelNotes | head -3 |
    xargs -I {} sh -c 'git show {}:RelNotes | sha1sum'
ce5501f9daadf110a20a4e4eccdfed63ef4b27e3  -
bd4d920214c4a48d8820292e24f020690595858d  -
5d47b511d86abd490fa4f2c2a8d4ef3589e1aecf  -
```

Answer (score 7):

There is a very quick way to get the Git hash for a file within some commit:

```
git rev-parse <commit-ID>:/path/to/file
```

Git's hash is a SHA-1 of the word `blob` followed by a space, followed by a decimal ASCII string giving the size of the file in bytes, followed by a NUL byte, followed by the file's contents:

```
size=$(wc -c $file)
(printf "blob %d\0" $size; cat $file) | sha1sum -
```

It looks from comments, though, like you want an actual SHA-1 of the file's contents (as someone else would get by extracting the file and running `sha1sum` on it), and not the *git* hash:

```
git show <commit-ID>:path | sha1sum -
```

is the general (non-bash-specific) method (bash's `<(` is fine as well, just make sure you have the fdesc file system mounted).

Comment: The commit ID can also be a branch name, or a hash, or any of the other ways of naming as given in `git help revisions`.  You can diff the files using the same naming method (ideal for looking at deviation between forks)

Answer (score 1):

At a minimum, you don't need to check out the commit.  `git show` can directly show you an object, including a blob.  You can send that into git hash-object without ever checking it out.

I think there should be a more efficient way, but you can do

```
git hash-object <(git show [commit]:[path])
```

So, for example,

```
$ git hash-object <(git show master:Makefile)
3fb4e1cbe0019c691a504e3419ece252db6f60ab
```

Comment: The tree of the commit already has a pointer to the blob object (the file). Depending on the OPs requirements, this might suffice.

Comment: That's awesome, thanks a lot. And it's even reasonably fast, under 3 seconds for whole history of more changed files in the project. This will help me a lot with some scripting :) Thanks again

Comment: @zebediah49: one question though, why does it show different string than `sha1sum file`? My working tree doesn't have any changes, so I would expect the first hash to be the same as output of `sha1sum file`.. I'm using this: `for commit in $(git log --oneline path/to/file | cut -d\  -f1); do git hash-object <(git show $commit:path/to/file); done`

Comment: I can replicate that behaviour without using the `git-show` part:  `git hash-object <file>` and `sha1sum <file>` produce different results.  Presumably, they are doing different things -- for example, the git command says that it "computes the object ID", which apparently is not just the SHA1 sum of its content.  E: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290444/why-does-git-hash-object-return-a-different-hash-than-openssl-sha1

Comment: well I guess I could just use `sha1sum - <(git show $commit:path/to/file)`?

Comment: You've combined the two ways of piping input into the command -- `sha1sum -` is asking for input on stdin, so you can use `git show [thing] | sha1sum -`, or you can use the anonymous pipe to pretend to give it a file `sha1sum <(git show [thing])`.  In this case, `sha1sum` sees that you told it to run on a file like `/dev/fd/XX`, which is a pipe created by the shell, with the other end attached to the `git show` command.  Using both is telling `sha1sum` to first hash standard in, and then to hash this named pipe.