# Is there a JGit plumbing API?

Tags: java, git, jgit

I need to use git plumbing commands (such as those used in [chapter 9 of the git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Git-Objects)) like `git hash-object`, `git write-tree`, `git commit-tree` and all the rest. Is there a nice API to do these in JGit (I can't seem to find one) or how would you do something basic like write from an output stream or file to a blob/what do you use instead of the git commands?

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to the [JGit API](http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/docs/jgit-2.0.0.201206130900-r/apidocs/index.html). Other than the high-level porcelain API in package `org.eclipse.jgit.api` the low level API isn't built in close correlation to the plumbing commands of native git. This is due to the fact that JGit is a Java library and not a command line interface.

If you need examples first look at the > 2000 JGit test cases. Next have a look into how EGit is using JGit. If this doesn't help come back and ask more specific questions.

Answer (score 1):

If there is, it should be in **[JGit](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit)**.

For instance, the `DirCache` object (ie, the Git Index) has a [WriteTree function](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/master/org.eclipse.jgit/src/org/eclipse/jgit/dircache/DirCache.java#L898-L918):

```
/**
 * Write all index trees to the object store, returning the root tree.
 *
 * @param ow
 *   the writer to use when serializing to the store. The caller is
 *   responsible for flushing the inserter before trying to use the
 *   returned tree identity.
 * @return identity for the root tree.
 * @throws UnmergedPathException
 *   one or more paths contain higher-order stages (stage > 0),
 *   which cannot be stored in a tree object.
 * @throws IllegalStateException
 *   one or more paths contain an invalid mode which should never
 *   appear in a tree object.
 * @throws IOException
 *   an unexpected error occurred writing to the object store.
 */
public ObjectId writeTree(final ObjectInserter ow)
```

Answer (score 1):

**git hash-object <file>**

```
import java.io.*;
import org.eclipse.jgit.lib.ObjectId;
import org.eclipse.jgit.lib.ObjectInserter;
import org.eclipse.jgit.lib.ObjectInserter.Formatter;
import static org.eclipse.jgit.lib.Constants.OBJ_BLOB;

public class GitHashObject {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File file = File.createTempFile("foobar", ".txt");
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        out.write("foobar\n".getBytes());
        out.close();
        System.out.println(gitHashObject(file));
    }

    public static String gitHashObject(File file) throws IOException {
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
        Formatter formatter = new ObjectInserter.Formatter();
        ObjectId objectId = formatter.idFor(OBJ_BLOB, file.length(), in);
        in.close();
        return objectId.getName(); // or objectId.name()
    }
}
```

Expected output : 323fae03f4606ea9991df8befbb2fca795e648fa
as discussed in [Assigning Git SHA1's without Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/552659/assigning-git-sha1s-without-git)

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for same thing like you.
I use git as a k-v database to describe our datastructure.
So I want to wrap git style Plumbing APIs or Jgit style Plumbing APIs as CRUD APIs.
Then I found org.eclipse.jgit.lib.ObjectInserter.

https://download.eclipse.org/jgit/site/5.10.0.202012080955-r/apidocs/index.html

https://download.eclipse.org/jgit/site/5.10.0.202012080955-r/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/lib/ObjectInserter.html

I think most C requirments of CRUD can be achieved by wrapping ObjectInserter.