# SHA-1 a string (git-hash-object string)

Tags: ruby, git, sha1, sha, digest

I am trying to encrypt SHA-1 the following string:

```
commit 218\0tree 64a7513fad0b86d34b6feedbf9c2e99135819861 parent 233634213baf3f40236233f28c6646f20786a80a author CTF user <me@example.com> 1390678027 +0000 committer CTF user <me@example.com> 1390678027 +0000 Give me a Gitcoin 200
```

It is a git `hash-object` input, with the header along with the commit message. The results I am getting are very different from one method to the other.

Using git hash-object, I get `bed6b1001619ad84548d05db65a75ac80bf79f31`.

Using Ruby's `digest/sha1`, I get `e729e36abf0fa4da392b8f2acc1561ec5d298af9`.

Using http://www.sha1-online.com, I get `d543ddbfb7607464f5f964b9a3536eccedd1e1a4`.

This is extremely confusing. Which one is it and why am I unable to mimic `git-hash-object`'s functionality? I read http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Git-Objects and followed the instructions there but I cannot seem to get the right hash digest.

Here is my ruby snippet:

`Digest::SHA1.hexdigest "commit #{body.length}\0#{body}"`

Is there a way in git to see the hash-object header, or the string it uses to hash out the SHA-1? What is wrong with my method above?

Comment: It isn't completely clear what problem you are trying to solve.  You might want to look at the answers for this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/552659/assigning-git-sha1s-without-git

Comment: @D.Shawley I am trying to get the git hash-object SHA-1 value manually instead of using git-hash-object. I looked at that question and I am doing precisely that.

Comment: Where did you get the string starting with `tree 64a751...`?  If you're comparing to an actual git commit, note that commit data contains embedded newlines, it's not all on one line.

Comment: @torek From git-write-tree. `tree` is on one line, `parent` is on another, `author` is on another and `committer` is on another. Then there are two new lines and then the commit message. With this, I get a SHA-1 of `56e4a594dc02c21dfa82c237e3b8c53ed9c8f4c5`. Still not `bed6b..`. Any idea what else I'm missing?

Comment: Ah, I meant more like, did you `git cat-file -p` an actual commit whose ID was known.  If I take your tree, parent, etc and put them in a file I get one that's at least 220 bytes long, including all newlines, which is longer than the 218 indicated, so I'm pretty sure there's some data out of sync here.

Comment: @torek You're correct. I had invalid newlines and data out of sync. I got it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

hello fellow stripe capture the flag contestant :)

this is how you do it (make sure that there is a newline!)

```
require 'digest/sha1'

content = "tree #{tree}
parent #{parent}
author CTF user <me@example.com> #{timestamp} +0000
committer CTF user <me@example.com> #{timestamp} +0000

Give me a Gitcoin

1
"

Digest::SHA1.hexdigest "commit #{content.length}\0#{content}"
```

Comment: The new line was the issue :) I was doing the same mistake in bash. Figured it out. Thanks!