# how to generate sha1 similar to git hash-object command

Tags: git, sha

Any idea why git hash-object has different outcome from shasum and openssl commands ?

```
➜ printf test | shasum
a94a8fe5ccb19ba61c4c0873d391e987982fbbd3  -

➜  printf test | git hash-object --stdin
30d74d258442c7c65512eafab474568dd706c430

➜  echo -n "test" | shasum
a94a8fe5ccb19ba61c4c0873d391e987982fbbd3  -
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/552659/how-to-assign-a-git-sha1s-to-a-file-without-git/552725#552725

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git adds a header which contains the **type** and **length** of the content and after that it generates the hash. That's why you are getting it different.

[Here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects#Object-Storage) is a more detailed description.